# Can not update records from one table into another

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a postcode database which contains postcodes and the lat and lon details, In another table i have a list of companies with postcodes and want to add the lat and lon details to matching postcodes, rather than use a join query etc.  Below is the code i am using, i have used something similar before, but i just can not work out why this isn't working.

```
$host    = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";
mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password );
mysql_select_db( $database ) or die( "Unable to select database" );


$query = "SELECT * FROM postcodes";      
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   



$postcode = $row['postcode'];   
$lat = $row['lat']; 
$lon = $row['lon']; 



$result = mysql_query("UPDATE companies SET lat ='$lat' and lng ='$lon'  
WHERE postal_code = '$postcode'") 
or die(mysql_error());  

}
```

The error I am getting is:  Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/visitrac/public_html/postcode.php on line 15

if i move the closed bracket so it is before the update then the error goes but no information gets into the database, which i assume is because it is out of the loop.  I have tried all sorts of things but nothing seems to work and so any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no need for the loop through the postcode results. You can update all companies in a single SQL statement.

```
UPDATE companies c
    INNER JOIN postcodes p
        ON c.postal_code = p.postcode
    SET c.lat = p.lat,
        c.lng = p.lon
```

Comment: OP said he does not want to use joins

Comment: @AnandPhadke: Unless OP can come up with a valid reason for imposing that restriction, that sounds unreasonable and leads to a much more expensive update process. I believe my answer is a much better way to accomplish this task.

Comment: sorry, i think i wrote that wrongly when i said about not using joins i meant taking the data out of the database as a join query and instead having the companies data updated.  I never thought of using a join as an update, so this is perfect thank you and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"UPDATE companies SET lat ='"+$lat+"' and lng ='"+$lon+"'   
 WHERE postal_code = '"+$postcode+"'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I made that change and it now gives this error:   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '55.017348077' at line 1